# How to combine post table and image table using sql left join and union

Tags: php, sql, oracle

How do i combine 3 tables `user table`, `post table` and `image table` to display post with image and post without image 
using sql inner join, left join and union.

Table Users

```
userid | uname |  pagename
-------|-------|-----
801    | peter |  a1
2      | john  |
```

Table Post

```
postid | postuserid | message
-------|------------|--------------
10     |  801       | This is post without image
101    |  801       | This is post with 2 images
102    |  801       | This is post with 1 image
```

Table Images

```
img | imgpostid | url
----|-----------|------------
1   | 101       | image1.png
2   | 101       | image2.png
3   | 102       | image01.png
```

My SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM Post pt
INNER JOIN Users us
ON pt.postuserid = us.userid
LEFT JOIN Images im
ON pt.postid = im.imgpostid
WHERE us.pagename = 'a1'
AND us.userid = 801
```

Expected result

```
This is post without image
This is post with 2 images [IMAGE1.PNG],[IMAGE2.PNG]
This is post with 1 image [IMAGE01.PNG]
```

The result i get

```
This is post without image
This is post with 2 images [IMAGE2.PNG]
This is post with 2 images [IMAGE2.PNG]
This is post with 1 image [IMAGE01.PNG]
```

Comment: Try using Left join instead of Inner join in your first join

Comment: @sobhanbagheri but i want to make sure that the user exist

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 
 [**Tips better SQL Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056)

Comment: @PhilipJems You can start your select query from user table to make that happen too

Comment: @sobhanbagheri please can you post the answer, i have tried many thing. Currently when one post has multiple image it will duplicate the post each post with one image

Comment: @PhilipJems All right

Comment: `102` and `101` doesnt have users so how you want bring those with `INNER JOIN`? you need `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @sobhanbagheri i have also update my question to help you understand what issue am facing with my current query

Comment: Remove the join to the images table, then put an inline query to the images table and wrap it with FOR XML to produce a CSV. Will post as an answer shortly.

Comment: Your query doesn't match that output because you don't have matching userid

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza see my updated post i have matching userid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you aggregate the images:

```
SELECT 
    imgpostid,
    LISTAGG(url, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY url) "imgs"
FROM Images
GROUP BY imgpostid
```

Then add the users

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4b01/23)

```
WITH i as (
  SELECT "imgpostid",
          LISTAGG("url", ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "url") "imgs"
  FROM Images
  GROUP BY "imgpostid"
)  
SELECT p."message", i."imgs" as images
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN users u
   ON p."postuserid" = u."userid"
LEFT JOIN i
   ON p."postid" = i."imgpostid"   
;
```

Comment: I swear i don't even understand how to use this query

Comment: What part you dont understand? You understand the first query at least?

Comment: Please the `This is post without image` in the sql query what is it for?

Comment: using `LEFT JOIN` you try to match post with images. If the Subquery `I` doesnt have any result for that post `imgs` will be null. In that case the `CASE` statement handle the result in the apropiate way. returnning `'This is post without image'` you should google `CASE expresions`

Comment: But `This is post without image` is an example message, it could another thing. I have also tried using your answer but it didn't work

Comment: what didnt work? did you get an error message? Consider create a sample demo in http://rextester.com

Comment: Ohh I thought you want a message with the count of how many images where on that post.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for string aggregation, namely `LISTAGG`:

```
select p.*, i.images
from posts p
left join
(
  select imgpostid, listagg(url, ',') within group (order by url) as images
  from images
  group by imgpostid
) i on i.imgpostid = p.postid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN posts 
ON users.userid = posts.postuserid
LEFT JOIN images
ON posts.postid = images.imgpostid
WHERE users.pagename = 'a1'
AND users.userid = 801
```

P.S: The query is not tested due I don't know your exact db schema